# How to verify duplication before append data in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to append data to my list only if it is distinct from previously stored data.

```
data <- c("A","B","C")
```

My code so far:

```
x<- function(...){
  
  data <- ifelse(... %in% data, append(data, ""),append(data, as.character(...)))
  return(data)
  
}
```

For instance, if I want to append  "D," my desired output is:

```
data
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

However, I received this:

```
 data
 [1] "A"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <- c("A","B","C")
y <- c("D", "A")

union(x, y)

# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

Answer (score 1):

`ifelse` function cannot give vector as a result. See [ifelse function documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/ifelse).

Instead, you should use `if - else` statement

```
x<- function(...){
  
  data <- if (... %in% data) {append(data, "")} else {append(data, as.character(...))}
  return(data)
  
}

x("D")

[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
x <- c("A","B","C")
y <- c("D", "A")

unique(c(x, y))

[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```